# Using HTTP proxy using Socket

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets, proxy

I am required to download web content including full headers like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sat, 30 Jul 2011 06:19:13 GMT
P3P: CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC CURa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR IND"
Date: Sat, 30 Jul 2011 06:20:13 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Set-Cookie: _SS=SID=0B3A2FD5AA7943BC92252BB73BD7C9CA; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: MUID=CE6F495249204D82A8F620B7317FC59E; expires=Mon, 29-Jul-2013 06:20:13 GMT; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: OrigMUID=CE6F495249204D82A8F620B7317FC59E%2c95e9e1eafdef40d6a24497335843fac6; expires=Mon, 29-Jul-2013 06:20:13 GMT; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: OVR=flt=0&flt2=0&flt3=0&flt4=0&flt5=0&flt6=0&flt7=0&flt8=0&flt9=0&flt10=0&flt11=0&ramp1=snrport4-release&release=or3&preallocation=0&R=1; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: SRCHD=D=1881020&MS=1881020&AF=QBLH; expires=Mon, 29-Jul-2013 06:20:13 GMT; domain=.bing.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: SRCHUID=V=2&GUID=A2EAC1B8990D46619C897016C94B5C4B; expires=Mon, 29-Jul-2013 06:20:13 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: SRCHUSR=AUTOREDIR=0&GEOVAR=&DOB=20110730; expires=Mon, 29-Jul-2013 06:20:13 GMT; domain=.bing.com; path=/

000037E4
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:Web="http://schemas.live.com/Web/"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" /><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
```

Since content with full headers is not available in WebClient, HttpWebRequest i am using Socket for the same, here is the code.

```
using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP))
{
    IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(fullUrlAddress);
    socket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
    socket.Connect(entry.AddressList[0], 80);

    string request = string.Empty;
    string build_request = string.Empty;
    if (cookieJar.Count != 0)
    {
        request = "GET {0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1}\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: {0}\r\nCookie: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        build_request = string.Format(request, requestedUri.AbsoluteUri, requestedUri.Host, GetCookies(requestedUri));
    }
    else
    {
        request = "GET {0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1}\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: {0}\r\nCookie: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        build_request = string.Format(request, requestedUri.AbsoluteUri, requestedUri.Host, "PREF=ID=19495678a6a3dd6e:U=c5ce8e4e3f61da69:FF=0:TM=1311310634:LM=1311310636:S=gbV7hD2dPfycsf8Q; NID=49=dN3QceFFBFxwsCXM43HCRJF_oxoBpUHuUWt2tpoofEDFcRhj7TWWV4EFQNuVYP1GhyBAsQr3oOeohsJp31x8kb_iXiGcQFh1a3IFsPTNKjzJv_NgSK8ssG956PJO7jH-");
    }

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(build_request);
    socket.Send(data, data.Length, 0);

    int bytes = 0;
    byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[10240];
    string currentBatch = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        do
        {
            bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived);
            currentBatch = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
            responseString.Append(currentBatch);
        }
        while (bytes > 0);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    socket.Close();
}
```

It is working perfectly, but i don't know how to connect using HTTP Proxy, Socket unlike WebClient cannot set proxy with UserName and Password.

My Question is Simple:
**How to connect using HTTP Proxy with Credentials in Socket?**

Please reply only if you have a solution, if you are recommending webclient or other dont reply, I have a strong reason to use Sockets, suggestions for open source libraries, links, tutorials invited.

Comment: One downside of using sockets is that a socket by itself doesn't now about HTTP proxies.  So your code above wouldn't connect if I ran it where I work (where all of our browsers are configured to connect to the internet via proxy).  The .NET runtime will sniff your internet settings from control panel and connect through the proxy if you use the WebClient or HttpWebRequest class.  Both appear to allow you to set cookies and headers, I don't know why you'd want to drop down to sockets.  Perhaps the answer below can be applied to your WebClient code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: WebClient does not let me login wordpress blogs, cos wordpress blogs sets some wired long cookie, which gets broken when handled by webclient, and httpwebrequest, but works when manually handled by sockets, thats the one and only reason to switch to socket, if i can get raw headers from WebClient or HttpWebResponse, then no need for sockets.

Comment: Did you evaluate if WebClient.ResponseHeaders contains the Set-Cookie fields?

Comment: why dont you try login, any wordpress blogs, try the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887491/httpwebresponse-raw-response-using-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username and password for a proxy are sent through the HTTP header.
Use the `Proxy-Authorization` field in your request header:

```
Proxy-Authorization: Basic <BASE64("USER:PASS")>
```

If any of your requests get a response "407 Proxy Authentication Required" you can read the response header field `Proxy-Authenticate` which will tell you the authentication mode to use when authorizing.
Above it's `Basic` (the most common one) but there are others like `Digest` and `NTLM`. You can read up on the other two [here](http://www.z9hg4bk.org/sip/hf/proxy-authorization.html)

Comment: Yeah, net bit rot, Internet Archive to the rescue! http://web.archive.org/web/20101126155446/http://www.z9hg4bk.org/sip/hf/proxy-authorization.html

Answer (score 1):

Your example is showing HTTP Response headers, not HTTP Request headers. What are the HTTP Request headers that you *need* to send that you cannot?

Doing this directly on a socket is going to be very, very, hard unless you make a bunch of simplifying assumptions (e.g. server never will use chunked encoding or compression, etc). For example, your current code won't work if the server uses keep-alive connections. You'd be far better off using the HTTPWebRequest and using Reflection to tweak any internal members you need.

Another alternative would be to put FiddlerCore into your application (www.fiddler2.com/core). FiddlerCore includes a complete HTTP stack, including support for proxies, compression, chunked-encoding, etc.