# HTTPWebResponse Raw Response, using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets, httpwebrequest

HTTPWebResponse exposes properties for Headers, is it possible to get **raw response like the once we get using socket**, Header and Content combined using **Reflection**, I think there must be a way.

I can use socket but a lot of work needed to make them usable, like proxy support, https, progress events, etc... list is long, i have been strongly advised to use HTTPWebRequest, only problem is i need the raw headers with the response, the websites i am trying to download sends a very long and weird cookie, which is not handled by HTTPWebRequest, WebClient. Wordpress blogs, not able to login any wordpress blog using WebClient, but with Sockets manual cookie handling it works perfect, may be a bug in WebClient.

**1) Just need the raw headers, that will do the trick.**

**2) And also [article link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Crawler.aspx#WebRequest)**

The article says HTTPWebRequest there is a problem, **only one thread is downloading while others are kept waiting**, if this is true then sockets are better??

***The article says:***
*This code works well but it has a very serious problem as the WebRequest class function GetResponse locks the access to all other processes, the WebRequest tells the retrieved response as closed, as in the last line in the previous code. So I noticed that always only one thread is downloading while others are waiting to GetResponse. To solve this serious problem, I implemented my two classes, MyWebRequest and MyWebResponse using Socket.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way to get raw headers:

```
var rawHeaders = request.GetResponse().Headers.ToString();
```

With your website and request you provided it returned:

```
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2011 12:08:49 GMT
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check;     path=/,wordpress_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/wp-admin,wordpress_sec_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/wp-admin,wordpress_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/wp-content/plugins,wordpress_sec_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/wp-content/plugins,wordpress_logged_in_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpress_logged_in_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpress_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpress_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpress_sec_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpress_sec_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpressuser_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpresspass_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpressuser_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/,wordpresspass_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; expires=Tue, 03-Aug-2010 12:08:49 GMT; path=/
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Last-Modified: Wed, 03 Aug 2011 12:08:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
Via: 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.6)
Connection: close
```

Does this solve your problem?

About Sockets instead of WebRequests - I would recommend against that approach. It is reinventing the wheel.

**UPDATE**

This does not solve the problem, as above headers are already parsed in a lossy way (see comments for details). Upon closer inspection I came to the conclusion, that raw header bytes are already lost after `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`.

The core parsing is done in `System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ParseHeaders()` or `System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ParseHeadersStrict()` (depending on the value of `System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.Section.UseUnsafeHeaderParsing`) and both methods fail to record the required information. Soon after, the buffer they operate on (`System.Net.Connection.m_ReadBuffer`) is filled with new data from the wire. The original headers are lost.

In order to save the raw data, you would need to reimplement the `System.Net.Connection` class, which is internal and hard-referenced by ServicePoint, which is public, but still hard-referenced by HttpWebRequest. To sum up, you would have to reimplement the whole stack.

So unless you can change the website behavior or live without these cookies, you will need to use a Socket. If that's the case, I would like to offer my condolences.

Comment: wordpress_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; see this, this is not a complete cookie, it gets broken, now try same with sockets, you will get full cookie.

Comment: Ok, now i get the picture. Truly weird (the following is a single cookie, as interpreted by firefox):
wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/

Comment: aslo the wordpress_c2d1208bd3bc2294298da94d67693495=+; part, is actually something like wordpress_6e7750f6a474de23330d1b7f0e9990c6=admin%7C1301039544%7C16d39b9f49cf062500d50471df7320e9; but is broken to half.

Comment: There is a private field in an internal class involved in the process called ``useUnsafeHeaderParsing``, which is set to false by default. Unfortunately, setting it to true doesn't help. Digging deeper...

Comment: I have encountered this as well, especially for duplicated headers (e.g. Set-Cookie) or anything with an embedded comma.  They store the string blob and then actually split on comma for GetValues!